# Média de execução Linux

Tags: python, linux, bash

Preciso pegar a média do tempo de execução e do consumo de `CPU de 30 execuções` de um programa feito em `Python`. Tenho que usar o comando `time` do `Linux`. Como nunca trabalhei com `Linux` antes estou tendo dificuldades para fazer isso.

Esse é o código que eu fiz até agora (não está funcionando). Alguém poderia me ajudar a fazer isso funcionar?

```
size=400
n_cpu=4

/usr/bin/time -f "CPU:  %p    TIME:  %e"
for i in {1..30};
do
    python "script.py" $size $size $n_cpu
done
```

Answer (score 1):

```
python -m timeit -n 30 script.py <…parâmetros…>
```

O [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) é um módulo padrão do Python, que te protege de todas as pegadinhas associadas com cronometrar código Python (e.g. quando você altera o código, o Python “recompila” o código que você escreveu; esse tempo é descontado pelo `timeit` mas não pelo Bash).

Comment: Isso também funciona com Jython, IronPython e Pypy?

Comment: Não faço a menor ideia, mas o módulo é [escrito em Python puro](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/timeit.py); o módulo que pode te causar mais problemas (por estar indisponível) é o `gc`, que expõe funcionalidades baixo-nível pro Python.

Comment: Está dando esse erro: NameError: global name 'ex1_threading' is not defined

Comment: Então não funciona. :(

Answer (score 1):

Para obter apenas o tempo, pode usar date

```
t0=$(date +%s)
for i in {1..5};
do
    sleep 1;
done
tf=$(date +%s)
echo "tempo de execução: $((tf - t0))"
```

Para utilizar o time do jeito que você tentou, precisa colocar o loop em uma nova seção do bash com o parâmetro -c

```
/usr/bin/time -f "CPU:  %p    TIME:  %e" bash -c "
for i in {1..5};
do
    sleep 1;
done "
```

Comment: @user25946: Usar o `time` pra microbenchmarks tipo esses que você parece estar fazendo não é ideal pelos motivos que eu mencionei — você está medindo outras coisas que não o tempo de execução do código — mas se você está usando interpretadores que não o CPython (ou _comparando_ os diferentes interpretadores) a solução do @Marcos é a correta.

Comment: Exato. Esse é um modo ruim de fazer o benchmark. Coloquei a resposta por causa da frase "tenho que usar o comando time do Linux".